# Iron-signal alternate in Polymer 2?

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

I have been using iron-signals almost everywhere in my application.

Now I was upgrading my polymer 1 application to polymer 2 and I found that `<iron-signals>` is not used anymore.

What is the alternate path to achieve the same. I basically want to pass data between different pages in my web app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to simply dispatch events on `window` from one element and listen for them in other elements.

### Example:

```
// Element 1

class FooElement extends Polymer.Element {
  connectedCallback() {
    super.connectedCallback()
  }

  ready() {
    super.ready()
    window.addEventListener('bar-was-called', e => {
      console.log(e.detail) // logs 'hello-bar'
    })
  }
}

// Element 2

class BarElement extends Polymer.Element {
  connectedCallback() {
    super.connectedCallback()
  }

  ready() {
    super.ready()
  }

  doBar() {
    window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('bar-was-called', { 
      detail: 'hello-bar' 
    }))
  }
}
```

### Side note

Keep in mind that `iron-signals` was removed for a reason. AFAIK it's that it promotes a hard-to-debug communications architecture.

From [`<iron-signals>` README](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-signals/blob/master/README.md):

> Note: avoid using iron-signals whenever you can use a controller (parent element) to mediate communication instead.

Comment: And how do I fetch data from the other side (other page that needs data)?

Comment: @Saransh That's a different question though isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Iron Signals have been deprecated in polymer 1.

Replace uses of iron-signals with iron-meta.